# Passing move_group object to callback function

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to pass an object created with `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface` class to a callback function from a `ros::Subscriber` in cpp. Any ideas on how this can be done?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285926/passing-move_group-object-to-callback-function/) by [nazir-ust](https://answers.ros.org/users/34228/nazir-ust/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See #q63991 and #q232204.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1